# Conform class extension to generic protocol function

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols, associated-types, generic-function

*** Short version ***

*How can I conform a class (extension) to a generic protocol function?*

*** Long version ***

This is a small part of a data structure to support a paginated collection,

```
protocol Pageable { 
     //an object whose can be in a collection
}

protocol Page{ //a page of a collection that can be paginated

    associatedtype PageItemType

    func itemAt<PageItemType:Pageable>(index: Int) -> PageItemType  
}

//Bonus question
//class PagedCollection<PageType:Page, ItemType:Pageable> {
    //...
//}
```

Here is the implementation of the protocols with a "real" case:

```
class Person : Pageable{}

class People {
    var people: [Person]?
}

//Mark: - Page

extension People: Page{ /*** error 1 ***/

    typealias PageItemType = Person

    func itemAt(index: Int) -> Person{
        let person : Person = self.people![index]
        return person
    }
}
```

Obtaining the following **error** (1):

> *Type 'People' does not conform to protocol 'Page'*
>
> > Protocol requires nested type 'PageItemType'

I also tried making it explicit but i just got a different error:

```
//Mark: - Page

extension People: Page{

    typealias PageItemType = Person

    func itemAt<PageItemType:Pageable>(index: Int) -> PageItemType{
        let person : Person = self.people![index]
        return person /*** error 2 ***/
    }
}
```

Obtaining the following **error** (2):

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'Person' to return type 'PageItemType'

So: *How can i let `itemAt` function return a valid type for the PageItemType typealias?

*** Bonus ***

**Bonus question** worth a 50 bounty (if answer is longer than a row i'll open a new question): 
Referring to the first code snippet `PagedCollection`

- given that each Page implementation has always a known implementation of Pageable protocol objet type
- is there a way to avoid declaring `ItemType:Pageable` ? Or at least enforce it with a `where` clause?

Comment: I guess the problem has to do with Swift not being able to infer that Person is a Pageable valud for PageItemType

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're conflating associated types with generic functions.

Generic functions allow you to provide a type to replace a given generic placeholder at the *call site* (i.e when you call the function).

Associated types allow types conforming to protocols to provide their own type to replace a given placeholder type in the protocol requirements. This is done *per type*, not at the call site of any function. If you wish to enforce a conformance requirement for an `associatedtype`, you should do so directly on its declaration (i.e `associatedtype PageItemType : Pageable`).

If I understand your requirements correctly, your `itemAt(index:)` function should be non-generic (otherwise the `associatedtype` in your protocol is completely redundant). The type that it returns is defined by the implementation of the type that conforms to `Page`, rather than the caller of the function. For example, your `People` class defines that the `PageItemType` associated type should be a `Person` – and that is what `itemAt(index:)` should return.

```
protocol Pageable {/* ... */}

protocol Page {

    // any conforming type to Page will need to define a
    // concrete type for PageItemType, that conforms to Pageable
    associatedtype PageItemType : Pageable

    // returns the type that the implementation of the protocol defines
    // to be PageItemType (it is merely a placeholder in the protocol decleration)
    func itemAt(index: Int) -> PageItemType
}

class Person : Pageable {/* ... */}

class People {
    var people: [Person]?
}

extension People : Page {

    // explicitly satisfies the Page associatedtype requirement.
    // this can be done implicitly be the itemAt(index:) method,
    // so could be deleted (and annotate the return type of itemAt(index:) as Person)
    typealias PageItemType = Person

    // the itemAt(index:) method on People now returns a Person
    func itemAt(index: Int) -> PageItemType {

        // I would advise against force unwrapping here.
        // Your people array most likely should be non-optional,
        // with an initial value of an empty array
        // (do you really need to distinguish between an empty array and no array?)
        let person = self.people![index]
        return person
    }
}
```

In regards to your implementation of a `PagedCollection` – as the `PageItemType` associated type in your `Page` protocol conforms to `Pageable`, I see no need for an `ItemType` generic parameter. This can simply be accessed through the associated type of the given `PageType` generic parameter.

As an example:

```
class PagedCollection<PageType:Page> {

    // PageType's associatedtype, which will conform to Pageable.
    // In the case of the PageType generic parameter being People,
    // PageType.PageItemType would be of type Person
    var foo : PageType.PageItemType

    init(foo: PageType.PageItemType) {
        self.foo = foo
    }
}

// p.foo is of type Person, and is guarenteed to conform to Pageable
let p = PagedCollection<People>(foo: Person())
```

Comment: Damn after a few days of struggling i think you finally let me get the typealiases in swift. Seems really all correct i test it once back to the office and i accept

Comment: 1. regarding the optional array, i have to, since it is feeded to a mapping library (can't touch that) and initialized not in the constructor. I am anyway doing all due checks ahead. Eventually will wrap it up once more. Thanks btw.
2. Rest works like a charm. Thank you so much, i didn' get that the aliases were excessible outside of class. Now after 3 days everything makes sense.

Comment: @jalone Ah okay, happy to help :)

Comment: Hi there, Can you take a look at my [last 4 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5175709/honey?tab=questions) and answer any of them you feel like?

Answer (score 2):

This is merely a formatted discussion from my [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178560/swift-associatedtype-discussion) with Hamish.

<sub>I'm writing it here, because chatrooms can get archived and sometimes a more direct QA can convey things differently</sub>

**Me:**

```
protocol Provider { 
    associatedtype Input 
    associatedtype Output 
    func value(forKey _key: Input) -> Output{} 
}
```

vs.

```
protocol Provider{ 
    func value<Input, Output>(forKey _key: Input) -> Output{} 
}
```

**Hamish:** Essentially the difference is where the placeholders are satisfied – associated types are satisfied at type level, whereas generic placeholders on a function are satisfied at the call-site of said function.

**Me:** I understand that level of difference. But is there any byproduct due to that difference :D

**Hamish:** What do you mean? they express different things – the former is a protocol where the conforming type only deals with one specific type of input and output, the latter is a protocol where the conforming type can deal with any given input and output types.

**Me:** *The former is a protocol where the conforming type only deals with one specific type of input and output.* What do you mean by specific? Can't the `typeAlias` be anything I like?

**Hamish:** It can, but it can only be satisfied once per type – once I define

```
struct S : Provider { 
   func value(forKey: String) -> Int 
}
```

`S` now can only deal with String inputs and Int outputs.
Whereas with the latter, I would define

```
struct S : Provider { 
    func value<Input, Value>(forKey _key: Input) -> Output{} 
}
```

now `S` has to be able to deal with *any* input and output type.